# Find if values of two columns are wrongly switched

Tags: r

I have a problem to solve. I need some code/idea for finding if, at a certain time, value of columns of a dataset are switched wrogly.

For example I have this dataset where column 1 could contain only (1,2) and column 2 could contain only (3,4)

```
Column 1    Column2
1               3
2               4
1               4
2               4
2               3
```

For something that went wrong at a certain time i see this:

```
Column 1      Column2

1                 3
2                 3
2                 3
1                 4
3                 1
4                 2
4                 1
3                 1
```

This is just an example for making my question clearer. How can i detect automatically when the values updated are put in wrong columns?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i was not clear. In my homework the dataset is daily updated and the number of observation is really really high. My purpose is sending a signal when a switch like the example happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can just swap the values whenever they are not in `c(1, 2)`, i.e.

```
d5[!d5$V1 %in% c(1, 2),] <- d5[!d5$V1 %in% c(1, 2), 2:1]
d5
#  V1 V2
#1  1  3
#2  2  3
#3  2  3
#4  1  4
#5  1  3
#6  2  4
#7  1  4
#8  1  3
```